# Erlang udp workers - want to have more udp listeners on same port

Tags: erlang, udp, pattern-matching, actor

I'm making a game server in Erlang and I want to be able to have one process for each connected client. This process is supposed to take care of all the UDP messages sent to the server by the client, by handling them and replying if necessary.

How do I achieve this? I know that with TCP I can put an arbitrary amount of listeners to run the function

```
gen_tcp:accept(ListenSocket)
```

and it will block the workers until work is available, etc. I want this behaviour with udp as well but I've been trying to make a simple example that spawns a new process that is supposed to match each udp packet depending on its ip and port, to see which player sent it, take the ones for himself and ignore the rest.

```
loop({Sock, Ip, Port}) ->
    receive
        {udp, Sock, Ip, Port, Msg} ->
            do_stuff & loop, etc.
    end
end.
```

Does this match the Ip from the loop to the message? And for this to work, I would need any other UDP listener to not match that specific packet for the worker to fetch each message it is supposed to at any given time, right? If another "general" UDP listener listens it could possibly pick the message before the worker.

So I'm asking if this approach would work or if I would get an error saying it is not an owner of the socket or something similar. So far I haven't gotten any worker to actually receive any message so I'm not sure if it's because of mismatching or because the socket only sends message to the currently controlling process, which I guess would make my plan impossible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The title of your question as well as the phrasing suggests you are trying to use UDP sockets like TCP.

#### TCP and UDP are different protocols

TCP is a connection-oriented protocol. Clients connect to servers, and a given server will have one socket per connection, plus one for listening. The network stack of the operating system routes incoming packets to the listening socket or the proper connected socket.

UDP is connectionless. **Your program will only have one UDP socket**. It will receive all UDP packets to the given port. You cannot spawn a process and get it to listen on the same port. So you cannot *have more udp listeners on same port* as you write in the title.

#### Considering the Erlang implementation

The common design pattern for TCP is to have one process handling the listening socket, spawning new worker processes for each connected sockets.

Since you try to implement something similar with UDP, you need to perform what the network stack does for you with TCP. You could have one process receiving packets and forwarding them to the proper worker process, spawning if required, based on source port and IP address. This process should maintain a table of all active "connections", i.e. all alive "streams" of packets.

Please also note that there is no close mechanism with UDP, so you should rely on timeouts, and maybe an additional mechanism in your protocol.

Filtering on a single socket on each process as you suggest in the comments is not possible because an Erlang socket in active mode sends packets to a single process (the controlling process). You could imagine some architecture where the packets are broadcast to all processes, each doing the filtering to select interesting packets.

However, you will see that this doesn't make sense in *your specific scenario* because you also need a mechanism to find out if a worker process should be spawned, and this mechanism eventually will tell you which process should handle the incoming packet. It could make sense if several workers were to process the same message.

Let's concretely see that with some code:

```
server_loop(Workers) ->
    receive
        {udp, Sock, Ip, Port, Msg} = UDPPacket ->
            % find out if we need to spawn a new worker.
            % typically, Workers is a gb_trees:tree().
            NewWorkers = case gb_trees:lookup({Ip, Port}, Workers) of
                none ->
                    NewWorkerPid = spawn_link(fun() -> worker_loop(Ip, Port) end),
                    gb_trees:insert(NewWorkerPid, Workers);
                {value, _WorkerPid} -> Workers  %% <- look, we have the worker!
            end,
            % broadcast to all workers.
            lists:foreach(fun({_, Worker} ->
                Worker ! UDPPacket
            end, gb_trees:to_list(NewWorkers)),
            server_loop(NewWorkers);
        % ... timeout callbacks from workers would go here
    end.
```

This is just an over-complicated version of what is hinted above, where the packet is sent to the proper worker each time.

```
server_loop(Workers) ->
    receive
        {udp, Sock, Ip, Port, Msg} = UDPPacket ->
            % find out if we need to spawn a new worker.
            % typically, Workers is a gb_trees:tree().
            {NewWorkers, Worker} = case gb_trees:lookup({Ip, Port}, Workers) of
                none ->
                    NewWorkerPid = spawn_link(fun() -> worker_loop(Ip, Port) end),
                    {gb_trees:insert(NewWorkerPid, Workers), NewWorkerPid}
                {value, WorkerPid} -> {Workers, WorkerPid}
            end,
            % send to worker.
            Worker ! UDPPacket,
            server_loop(NewWorkers);
        % ... timeout callbacks from workers would go here
    end.
```

Comment: I know the difference between the two. I want to use UDP as if it was TCP in the way that I want to be able to have a specific process handle a specific client, because I will be matching the players of the game by ip instead of nick (so I don't have to parse the string). I know it is connectionless but that would be implemented by me with timeouts etc.

Once a player logs in, a process will be spawned which will then listen to the UDP socket but will only read messages related to its own client. Matched with IP that is.

Reason for this is because I want to be able to have a lot of players.

Comment: Basically, you did not answer my question. My question was regarding the pattern matching. Would the matching work? Or is only one process allowed to ever receive messages through said socket, meaning I can't just pass it around to the workers?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. You server will only have one UDP socket, and your proposed implementation is not possible. Your question about pattern matching is actually unrelated, but yes, the pattern itself would work to filter incoming packets. You can match on bound variables (`Sock`, `Ip` and `Port` here). However, this is a bad idea as all unfiltered packets will remain and accumulate in the message queue.

Comment: But that would be taken care of in some other way. I am just interested in if that approach is technically possible. Filtering message on the same socket but from different processes. So this is related, because my question was actually if I could use different processes to filter on the same socket. Anyway, this was my question, so if this was unclear I am sorry. All other messages not filtered would be taken care of the main process.

Comment: Having several processes receive message from a single UDP socket is not possible.

Comment: I wish that you actually don't go into details about how to solve the problem because that's up to me to do on my own. And I already had a plan on how to do it in case what I actually asked would work. So there is really no point in you adding that code there because you just assumed I would solve it in another way than I intended to do. So you adding that code does not matter. If you would be so kind as to make the answer to my real question more visible I would appreciate that. That question being a) Can I listen from different workers on same UDP socket? and b) Would filtering work?